# Can this integral similar to the Fourier transformation of $\delta$ function be calculated analytically?

Tags: fourier-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, branch-points

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dk\ \exp\left[i\big(kx-\sqrt{k(k-b)}\big)\right]$$

where $x$ and $b$ are both real. If $b=0$, the integral reduces to the Fourier transformation of a Dirac $\delta$ function. However, the integrand has two branch points, i.e. $k=0$ and $k=b$, here. Can this integral be calculated analytically, such as using residue theorem?

Comment: When $\displaystyle\large b=0$, you'll get
$\displaystyle\large \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(\,{\rm  i}\left[\,kx - \left\vert\, k\,\right\vert\,\right]\,\right)\,{\rm d}k$: It's not reduced to anything related to the Dirac $\displaystyle\large \delta$.

Comment: @Felix Marin Surely, the expression shown in the question is ambiguous. However, the integral is required to be the Fourier transform of $\delta$ function as $b=0$. To avoid the ambiguity, we can change the integrand to $\exp[i(kx-k\sqrt{(k-b)/k})]$

Comment: Now, it's fine. Thanks.